# pandas_udf giving error related to pyarrow

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, pyarrow

I have dataframe where I want to get the lat_long for the given geolocation using polyline library in pysaprk

```
+-----------------+--------------------+----------+                             
|              vid|        geolocations| trip_date|
+-----------------+--------------------+----------+
|58AC21B17LU006754|eurnE||yqU???????...|2020-02-22|
|2T3EWRFV0LW060632|uocbGfjniOK[Fs@rC...|2020-02-25|
|JTDP4RCE0LJ014008|w}wtFpdxtM????Q_@...|2020-02-25|
|4T1BZ1HK8KU029845|}rz_Dp~hhN?@?@???...|2020-03-03|
```

I am using pandas_udf and apache arrow has been enabled

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, pandas_udf
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled", "true")
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.fallback.enabled", "true")

lat_long_udf = pandas_udf(lambda geoloc:  polyline.decode(geoloc)[0],ArrayType(StringType()))
df1=df.withColumn('lat_long',lat_long_udf(df.geolocations))
```

When calling df.count() is giving result but when doing df.show() ,I am getting error like this:

```
 248, in init_stream_yield_batches
    for series in iterator:
  File "/Users/prantik.pariksha/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 450, in mapper
    result = tuple(f(*[a[o] for o in arg_offsets]) for (arg_offsets, f) in udfs)
  File "/Users/prantik.pariksha/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 450, in <genexpr>
    result = tuple(f(*[a[o] for o in arg_offsets]) for (arg_offsets, f) in udfs)
  File "/Users/prantik.pariksha/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 110, in <lambda>
    verify_result_type(f(*a)), len(a[0])), arrow_return_type)
  File "/Users/prantik.pariksha/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/util.py", line 107, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "/Users/prantik.pariksha/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/polyline/__init__.py", line 16, in decode
    return PolylineCodec().decode(expression, precision, geojson)
  File "/Users/prantik.pariksha/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/polyline/codec.py", line 43, in decode
    lat_change, index = self._trans(expression, index)
  File "/Users/prantik.pariksha/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/polyline/codec.py", line 31, in _trans
    byte = ord(value[index]) - 63
TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 87 found




>>> print(pandas.__version__)
1.1.1
>>> print(numpy.__version__)
1.19.1
>>> import pyarrow
>>> print(pyarrow.__version__)
1.0.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are most likely getting this error because a `pandas_udf` takes a pandas Series as input and you are applying the `decode` function directly to this series, instead of applying it to the values within the pandas Series.

E.g. in the example below, I expanded your lambda function a bit so that you can see it. I take the pandas series, apply the `polyline.decode` function to this series and then return the resulting series again. Note that I also changed the return type to `ArrayType(DoubleType())` instead of `ArrayType(StringType())`.

```py
import pandas as pd

from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, DoubleType

....


df = spark.createDataFrame([["~sqU__pR_jpv@_pR"], ["_~t[__pR~qy@_pR"]], ["geolocations"])


@pandas_udf(ArrayType(DoubleType()))
def lat_long_udf(s: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
  return s.apply(lambda x: polyline.decode(x)[0])


df1=df.withColumn('decoded', lat_long_udf(df.geolocations))
df1.collect()
```